# Threads appear to get executed in sequence Python

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from threading import Thread 
def test_first(*args):
    '''
    some code 
    :param args: 
    :return: 
    '''
td_num = Thread(target=test_first([1,2,3,4,5]))
td_char = Thread(target=test_first(['A','B','C','D','E']))
td_welcome = Thread(target=test_first("Welcome"))

td_num.start()
td_char.start()
td_welcome.start()

td_num.join()
td_char.join()
td_welcome.join()
```

I have one function which i'm calling from multiple threads, but instead of executing in parallel it is executing in sequence. Any suggestion what wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the functions when you pass them to `Thread`.

This:

```
Thread(target=test_first([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

first calls the function `test_first()`, then passes the *result of the function* to `Thread()`. That means the function is called and complete before the thread is created.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) are pretty clear:

> target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method.
> Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

You should instead pass the callable directly to the `Thread` and pass the arguments in separately:

```
td_num = Thread(target=test_first, args=([1,2,3,4,5],))
```

Comment: What if I have two function and return of  function test_first is going to be used as the argument of second function test_second, so in this case how we can implement the thread. for e.g.

td_num = Thread(target=test_second(test_first([1,2,3,4,5])))

Comment: @VivekKumar the way Python works is that it evaluates function arguments *before* passing them to the function. So if you do `Thread(target=test_second(test_first([1,2,3,4,5])))` it will evaluate both functions and pass the result to `Thread` that's not very useful. You need to use  `args` and pass a reference to the function without calling it.