# How to prevent class contructor from blocking other threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-class

I am new to threading, so this question might be too basic.
I have two classes A and B. If I put their respective instances and methods in two threads as below:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        sleep(10)
        print('class A __init__ awake')

    def method_a(self):
        sleep(10)
        print('method_a awake')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        sleep(1)
        print('class B __init__ awake')

    def method_b(self):
        sleep(5)
        print('method_b awake')


thread_a = Thread(target=A().method_a)
thread_b = Thread(target=B().method_b)
thread_a.start()
thread_b.start()
```

my expected result would be:

```
class B __init__ awake
method_b awake
class A __init__ awake
method_a awake
```

but I am getting:

```
class A __init__ awake
class B __init__ awake
method_b awake
method_a awake
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I am passing my methods to `Thread` instance or something more fundamental?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Threads appear to get executed in sequence Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833459/threads-appear-to-get-executed-in-sequence-python)

Comment: `target=A()` the damage is already done.

Comment: @ Ahmed AEK Actually not because the issue is with the class constructor specifically, the methods run exactly as I expect them to (i.e. not in sequence)

Comment: @ Ahmed Makes sense, any idea how to pass A to Thread correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most straight forward way to do it is to wrap the object creation and function execution in a function that does both, that will be executed entirely in another thread.

```py
thread_a = Thread(target=lambda: A().method_a())
thread_b = Thread(target=lambda: B().method_b())
```